# Tags for VPC with --tag-specifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

EC2 has options to create tags; can we add tags using cli to VPC or any other ARN with the --tag-specifications? I have tried the following

`aws ec2 create-vpc 
--cidr-block 193.164.0.0/16 
--instance-tenancy default 
--tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]' 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=cost-center,Value=cc123}]'`

Error:
`Unknown options: --tag-specifications, ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=cost-center,Value=cc123}], ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check if an aws.exe command supports an option use the --generate-cli-skeleton command line option. Example:

```
aws ec2 create-vpc --generate-cli-skeleton
```

The output from this command is:

```
{
    "CidrBlock": "",
    "AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock": true,
    "DryRun": true,
    "InstanceTenancy": "host"
}
```

From the command output you can verify that there are no options for tags.

In your question you asked about tagging VPCs. Here is an example command for this case:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources vpc-30783443 --tags Key=Network,Value=Default
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the command in one line. Don't run it in multiple lines.

For example:

```sh
aws ec2 create-vpc --cidr-block 10.0.0.0/16 --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=vpc, Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=EMR-VPC}]'
```

Comment: Copying this literally gives: `Unknown options: --tag-specifications, ResourceType=vpc, Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=EMR-VPC}]`

Answer (score 2):

`--tag-specifications` is a relatively new feature in AWS CLI.

As of now (AWS CLI 1.11.178), only EC2 **instances** and **volumes** can be tagged when the resource is created. Tagging VPC when creating it is not supported yet.

Comment: You are right! I found this relevant article for other service that do not have tagging configured yet. Link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html

Answer (score 1):

There is now an option to tag VPCs when using the [AWS Tools for Powershell Cmdlet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-welcome.html).

This can be achieved by specifying the tags you wish to use first, creating the VPC and applying the tags thereafter. 
For example:

```
# Name Tag for the VPC
$TagVPCName = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag
$TagVPCName.Key = "Name"
$TagVPCName.Value = "Tenancy/Customer 0"

# Name Tag for Other Services
$TagVPCPurpose = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag
$TagVPCPurpose.Key = "Purpose"
$TagVPCPurpose.Value = "Dev Environment"

$network = '172.16.0.0/16'
New-EC2Vpc -CidrBlock $network -InstanceTenancy default -Region
New-EC2Tag -Resource $EC2VPC.VpcId -Tag $TagVPCName
New-EC2Tag -Resource $EC2VPC.VpcId -Tag $TagVPCPurpose
```

Further information can be found at:

https://spr.com/powershell-function-provision-windows-server-ec2-instance-aws-cloud/

https://github.com/jbernec/AmazonWebServices/blob/master/New-AWSNonDefaultEC2Instance.ps1

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/powershell/latest/reference/